# .NetCore WebAPI methods Async or Not with EFCore query

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core

What is considered best(or better) practice to have as default state and why, and what are the real benefits of either?
For example if we have *Get* method in controller should it be:

```
public virtual IActionResult Get(int page = 1, int pageSize = 100)
{
    var q = repository.Query().AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<UserViewModel>();
    q = q.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    return new OkObjectResult(q);
}
```

or

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Get(int page = 1, int pageSize = 100)
{
    var q = repository.Query().AsNoTracking().ProjectTo<UserViewModel>();
    q = q.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    return new OkObjectResult(await q.ToListAsync());
}
```

If **async** is prefered is this code good for it and enough?
Also *Query()* in *repository* is simply
`public virtual IQueryable<User> Query() { return context.Set<User>().AsQueryable(); }`

I have found here that **async** was in fact slower:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5816
That bug was apparently fixed, but I don't know what are performance comparison in the latest version.

Comment: Frist one will block the request thread, so in high load/traffic scenarios you it will sooner than later start returning http 500 errors to the callers once all threads are used up. P.S. use the correct tags in future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefits of `async/await` over regular, synchronized code, is biggest when your server is under heavy enough load that freeing up threads on the thread pool makes a difference. Before then, the overhead of context tracking and switching can easily be bigger than the performance gains of freeing up threads.

I tend to favor using the asynchronous API over the synchronous, mainly because I've been in a few projects where high load and synchronous code was a high enough problem that someone decided it was time to refactor and move to `async`, and it was a pain every time. It's also becoming more and more common to only expose `async` API:s (for example, the Azure SDK has many `async` actions which don't have synchronous counterparts), which means that you might *have* to perform such a re-write later, if you end up using such an API.

But if performance is the only thing you want to take into account, you need to profile your application under realistic load and see which approach works best.

---

Addendum:

It's quite easy to introduce more of the `async`/`await` overhead than necessary. A good rule-of-thumb I like to use is to think of three types of methods that can return `Task` or `Task<T>`, and follow one of these patterns for each, respectively:

- Methods that are actually synchronous (but return `Task` or `Task<T>`, e.g. in order to allow for overloading with asynchronous variants): return with `Task.FromResult`.

  ```
  public Task<string> ActuallySynchronousGetter()
  {
      return Task.FromResult("foo");
  }
  ```
- Methods that forward to an asynchronous method, but don't do anything else: just return the `Task`, no need to `await` it.

  ```
  // note: no async/await, just Task<T>
  public Task<string> ForwardingGetter()
  {
       return SomeOtherGetter(); // also with return type Task<string>
  }
  ```
- Actual asynchronous methods, that both do something asynchronous (usually I/O) and then work with the result of that asynchronous operation: *this is the only time you actually need the `async` and `await` keywords*.

  ```
  public async Task<string> GetStringAsynchronously()
  {
       var str = await SomeOtherGetter();
       return str.Replace("foo", "bar"); // note: we need the actual string here
  }
  ```

Your code seems to fall in the third case - you need the result of `.ToListAsync()` in order to pass it to the `OkObjectResult` constructor. I would probably have written the entire thing as one statement, but it's mostly a matter of taste:

```
var data = await repository.Query()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ProjectTo<UserViewModel>()
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToListAsync();
return new OkObjectResult(data);
```

[Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) writes a lot and in depth about how `async` and `await` works, and how you should (and should not) use it.

Comment: So is the code in second example fine for that, specifically can async-await code be only in controller leaving repository as it is?

Comment: @borisdj See my updated answer for some more guidelines.

Comment: Like your code taste.
So this fails third case because of repository.Query(), and if so how should that method look like ?

Comment: I think your current implementation of `repository.Query()` is fine.

Comment: Now I am little confused, what exactly was the problem then, and did your code(in one statement) solved it or it is the same.
Only structural difference I could assume is 'await' key being in front of 'repository', if that has any difference at all.
Or this Get function simply does not have 3rd case situation.

Comment: No, there was no big problem. I re-styled the code to what I deem more readable, but that's - as stated - a matter of taste. The `await` keyword moves because I inlined the variable `q`, but otherwise our two code snippets are basically identical.

Comment: In that case conclusion is that 'async' is better and second example itself is fine for this situation (getting list of items from controller).